# Doppelgänger answers

Tags: bug, answers

Few days ago I was editing an answer on ProgSE (few minutes after I had posted it), and when I saved the edit it was posted as a separate answer. Didn't think much of it at the time, but today I spotted another doppelgänger answer here on MSO.

The answers are on these questions, and you'll need 10K+ on the respective sites to see the doppelgängers:

- [Tried teaching myself to program before college, accidently overwhelmed myself, tips?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/176349/tried-teaching-myself-to-program-before-college-accidently-overwhelmed-myself)
- [I don't know agile software development. Where do I ask questions about it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156477/i-dont-know-agile-where-to-ask-questions-about-it)

Comment: I once [had that happen with one of my posts on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/104162/134300), but I was unable to reproduce and figured I probably confused myself and somehow reposted.

Comment: @Chichiray I'm pretty sure I didn't, but then again I posted the answer early in the morning, it's possible I wasn't properly caffeinated at the time.

Comment: [I've seen something like this before too](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140431/question-with-answer-listed-twice).

Comment: I had this happen to me. Can't find the post, but I assumed it was just because I hit answer instead of edit. ;) Maybe that user did the same thing, and somehow localStorage got involved in populating the answer field, making it "feel" like one was actually editing...